# Trim leading and update in mysql

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create a query in MYSQL that would trim the leading '# ' from all of the fields in a column.

```
update values set value = TRIM(LEADING '# ' from value)
```

However, doing this gives me an error

> Duplicate entry '3002' for key value

The value column has a unique constraint and the error probably occurs because the query is trying to set the same value to all of value column after trimming.

Is there a way to do trim leading and update in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query looks fine.

The issue might be here. Let me give you an example.

Case 1:
At row-x, you have value '#info' and at row-y you have info.

You removed the # from row-x in your query. Now you have already info value at row-y. You can not update the new value to info as it is there already.

I would suggest either to remove the UNIQUE constraint or you do not update the database itself. You can trim with your backend programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is not setting all values to the same value, this is where once trimmed you now have two different rows with the same value for that column.

To find this:

```
SELECT id, value, TRIM(LEADING '# ' from value) AS trimmed_value ORDER BY trimmed_value
```

Presuming you have some kind of `id` column you'll be able to find any rows where `trimmed_value` is identical.